# How to catch Unhandled Exceptions on Worker Services (Windows Services) .NET 5?

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-5

Does anyone know how to catch all the exceptions from worker services (Windows Services) on .NET5? I get it on Web Services but not on worker services.

Thank you!